# How to generate dynamic html data in tooltipster

Tags: jquery, ajax, tooltip, tooltipster

I have a page where users list is shown. Now i want if user hover on a users Name the then the detail of that particular user should be fetched from server & shown in tooltip

how can i achieve it, i know that i have to pass data-id or something in post but I'm totally new in this jquery so i need a lil help

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    content: 'Loading...',
    // 'instance' is basically the tooltip. More details in the "Object-oriented Tooltipster" section.
    functionBefore: function(instance, helper) {

        var $origin = $(helper.origin);

        // we set a variable so the data is only loaded once via Ajax, not every time the tooltip opens
        if ($origin.data('loaded') !== true) {

            $.get('http://example.com/ajax.php', function(data) {

                // call the 'content' method to update the content of our tooltip with the returned data
                instance.content(data);

                // to remember that the data has been loaded
                $origin.data('loaded', true);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you add your html?

Comment: You will need a data source on a server that replies to the ajax requests. Do you have an idea for that yet? Will it reply json?

Comment: Did you go through https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/? Any difficulties with it?